# Aptana 3 how to use a project in another project without copying files, in order to keep them in sync?

Tags: aptana

I have a javascript project that is still in development;
Then I have another rails project that will use the javascript project;

I would like to have in "my-rails-project/public/javascript/" the link to the other javascript project.
I would like to be able to make changes within the rails-project and affect the javascript-project.

Is this possible and how?
thanks (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is general Eclipse thing and not related to Aptana in particular.
Simply start creating a new Folder and on the wizard page click "Advanced>>>", then choose Linked Folder and Browse to location of your javascript project.
That's it.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Any idea what the error message saying `Project 'myProject' is mapped to repository type 'com.aptana.git.core.GitRepositoryProvider' which does not support linked URIs.` means when I try to follow your answer to import another project to 'myProject'?

Comment: @kontur - The way I resolved this issue was doing it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070017/how-to-import-a-git-non-eclipse-java-project-into-eclipse