# Detecting code smells in git repository using Eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, pmd

I need to find code smells in the Eclipse project git repository.

I am trying to do this via EGit for Eclipse and plugins PMD and JDeodorant. But I seem to be having trouble.

I have managed to clone the git repository into Eclipse but I cannot use PMD or JDeodorant on its files. Why is that?

If I have a normal Java project, those tools work. So I am guessing I need to convert the git repo into a java project - how do I even do that?

[image]

Thanks to the answer below, I have managed to covert the repository into Eclipse projects, but the only thing not making sense are red exclamation marks:

[image]

Comment: This may be will help you !

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070017/how-to-import-a-git-non-eclipse-java-project-into-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the repository, choose "Import Projects..." and then "Import existing projects".