# Error While importing Openfire3.9.3 from GitHub to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, installation, openfire

I am trying to customize openfire and this is the first time i am even working with openfire.

I have installed the Openfire server in the local machine and it works fine.
I want to customize the Openfire Source code to meet my needs. Even making a Plugin for the Initial Purpose will do, So I have clones the latest release from GitHub.

While I tried to Import the project to Eclipse, it's not able to get any project file.
I have checked the tutorial provided by Openfire on how to setup the Eclipse environment for development but its deprecated and the SVN repository doesn't work any more [Tutorial Link Here for Openfire Eclipse Setup](https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1020).

How would you set up the Eclipse environment for Openfire?
I am using Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `.project` Eclipse file in the [igniterealtime/Openfire](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire), and the official [source build documentation page](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/master/documentation/docs/source-build.html) mentions using [`ant`](http://ant.apache.org/).

So you would need to:

- [import that repo as a general project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Use_the_New_Projects_Wizard)
- then [convert it as a Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8070430/6309)